# "ORA-00936 missing expression" on eclipselink jpa named-native-query, but working in standalone client

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, nativequery

I have a sql query not working when parsed from jpa named-native-queries xml file - it fails due to ORA-00936 missing expression (jpa vendor is eclipselink).

Tough, it works on standalone sql clients.

Below the code:

```
select c.CASENUMBER,
    pdf.IDDOCUMENT, pdf.CONTENT as pdfFile,
    odt.CONTENT as odtFile, 
    dc.CREATIONDATE, dc.ALGORITHM, dc."RESULT", dc.DETAILS AS detailsFile
from document pdf
    inner join document odt on odt.IDDOCUMENT = pdf.IDMASTERDOCUMENT
    inner join DOCUMENTCHECK dc on dc.iddocument = pdf.iddocument
    inner join caselab c on pdf.idcase = c.idcase
where dc.processed = 1 and dc.result != 'OK'
    and trunc(dc.PROCESSINGDATE) like sysdate
```

Comment: This isn't your error, but the code makes no sense:  `trunc(dc.PROCESSINGDATE) like sysdate `.  Using `like` on a `date` !?!

Comment: processingdate is a timestamp - perhaps oracle is able to translate sysdate in a formate like-ly as timestamp -- oracle or my sql clients (plsql, dbeaver).

However, it does NOT work also removing that last line (= "trunc(dc.PROCESSINGDATE) like sysdate"). I already tried to remove that, without luck

Comment: . . `like` is not appropriate for date comparisons.  There are lots of built-in functionality for that purpose.

Comment: **NEVER** use LIKE with DATE or TIMESTAMP values.

Comment: ok ok ok, I understand. no like for date, timestamp or whatever *date/time*. however, also removing that last 'and' clause, the error is still there

Comment: Rewrite it from scratch. Begin with selecting a single column from just one table. Then add another column. Then join the second table. And so forth, until you find the culprit.

Comment: Show the actual exception - EclipseLink should show the SQL it is executing as is. If it is missing a clause, I suspect your quotes aren't escaped properly or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

finally, the error was in quoting "result" (dc."result"); I have quoted it since sql client (plsql as for as dbeaver) suggested so ('result' is a keyword?): without quotes it does not work in standalone client (perhaps, due to some hidden preference...).
However, removing quotes it works fine within queries xml file